# Spark Dataframe write to hive failed with Zero length BigInteger error

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, persist

My Spark program pulls data from SQL server DB using JDBC, it was running fine from few months, It is throwing following error now.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:302)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getDecimal(UnsafeRow.java:439)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply2077_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I created a scaled down version of the program to just pull sample 10 records, persist RDD and write to hive table. This is also failing with same error.
I tried following things:

1. Pull only non numeric fields, persisting RDD and write to table
   --> Successful
2. Pull only numeric fields,persisting RDD and write to table --> Successful
3. Pull all columns and write to table without persisting RDD --> Successful

Getting error only when I pull both numeric and non numeric fields, persist the RDD (rdd.persist) and write to hive table.
I am using Spark 1.6.1, Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Somewhere you probably have an empty `String` where Spark expects a number (to be converted to `BigInteger`). Incidentally, when you say "Getting error only when I persist the RDD," do you mean writing to the table? Or do you mean calling `rdd.persist()` which is a real thing but probably not what you mean. Just making sure.

Comment: Getting error only when I pull all fields, do rdd.persist and then write the data to hive table.

Comment: @Remo Do you find any solution ?